# Что за ошибки при отправке ajax-запроса?

Tags: header, ajax

Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"<br>
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"<br>
Вот такие вот(выдаёт консоль ошибок Хрома, на работоспособности не отображается, но раздражает)

Comment: код в студию

Comment: xmlHttp.open("POST", "update_colors.php", true);<br>
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", send_post.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = refreshPageColors;
xmlHttp.send(send_post);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать вот эти 2 строки :)

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", send_post.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Это связано с возможной "атакой" - HTTP Request Smuggling, браузеры игнорируют эти 2 хеадера, и выбрасывают ворнинг.

Comment: спасибо, пропала ошибка